# Segmentation fault at Serial.begin()

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, compile

I try to communicate with my Arduino clone (Elegoo Uno R3) from Arduino IDE (v1.8.4 installed by `dnf` from repos) at Fedora 27. Compiling and upload of normal example code works well. However, as I try to start any serial communication (e.g. for debug), the compiler fails returning following segfault:

```
"/usr/bin/avr-gcc"  -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "/tmp/arduino_build_407070/AnalogReadSerial.ino.elf" "/tmp/arduino_build_407070/sketch/AnalogReadSerial.ino.cpp.o" "/tmp/arduino_build_407070/../arduino_cache_983152/core/core_arduino_avr_uno_1621df717313d057c92202babd71649a.a" "-L/tmp/arduino_build_407070" -lm
lto1: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://bugzilla.redhat.com/> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: /usr/bin/avr-gcc returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/6.3.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

I found similar issue here https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/issues/486 However, that solution deals with Arduino-Makefile software that is little bit complex for me.

I would appreciate any help either how to solve the segfault itself, or how to easily use Arduino-Makefile (I would like to compile from Arduino IDE or any user-friendly IDE).

Comment: What IDE version are you running? And how did you install it?

Comment: How did `avr-gcc` find its way into `/usr/bin`?  How exactly have you installed Arduino?  Are you intentionally using an avr-gcc different than the one packaged with it, or is that an accidental case of a system version overriding Arduino's?

Comment: Edited the question - version 1.8.4, installed from repos. I didn't setup any magic with avr-gcc - I did not change anything.

Comment: @ChrisStratton `which arduino` provided `/usr/bin/arduino`, then `find /usr/bin/arduino -name avr-gcc` did not output anything. `ls -l /usr/bin/avr-gcc` gives `-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 830016 Aug  2 20:40 /usr/bin/avr-gcc` and /usr/bin/avr-gcc --version` gives `avr-gcc (Fedora 6.3.0-3.fc27) 6.3.0`

Comment: @ChrisStratton I installed using `sudo dnf install arduino`. The blink works as it should. I also tested a switch and it works as well. Is it possible to download the binary and run it along the redhat version?

Comment: Do not install from repos. Download the official tarball from Arduino.

Comment: If you install the download in a unique path, probably, but safer to remove the redhat version with their package manager.  This looks to be the same as the bug the Arduino-Makefile project is talking about, applying to at least the fedora type avr-gcc package over a wide range of versions.  You might be able to fix it if you can get the IDE to add the build flag they discuss, but simpler just to use the working download from Arduino unless you particularly want to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for help! The official Arduino binaries did the trick :) Could you please transform the comment into an answer as I could then upvote and accept it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of the avr-gcc package that's currently available in the updates-testing repo that should fix the problem. You can install/update it by enabling the updates-testing repo, or grabbing the rpm from koji (https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1013122)